# Error: package 'rqt_plot' not found

Tags: ros-melodic, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Backgrounds:

---

I am studying this page:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics
in:
Melodic
Ubuntu 18.04

---

My questions:
When:
$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot

I saw:
[rospack] Error: package 'rqt_plot' not found

Why?
How to slove it?

Note:
I checked in /opt/ros/melodic/share, there are rqt_graph,rqt_gui,rqt_gui_py,nothing about rqt_plot.

Thank you for your kindness and your next answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348485/error:-package-%27rqt_plot%27-not-found/) by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$ sudo apt-get install ros--rqt

$ sudo apt-get install ros--rqt-common-plugins

---

Originally posted by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) with karma: 17 on 2020-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1